# Upgrade deprecated autoDeleteImages property gives AccessDeniedException - DescribeRepositories?

Tags: aws-cdk

Deploying after changing the ECR `Repository` property from `autoDeleteImages` to `emptyOnDelete` results in error:

```
AccessDeniedException ... because no identity-based policy allows the ecr:DescribeRepositories action
```

```ts
     this.ecr = new Repository(this, 'Ecr', {
       repositoryName: "test-ecs-api-svc",
       removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
       // otherwise won't be able to destroy on removal
       // autoDeleteImages: true,
       emptyOnDelete: true,
     });
```

How to get rid of the deprecated property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to do it in two `deploy` steps:

1. remove the deprecated usage of the `autoDeleteImages` property
2. run `cdk deploy`
3. add the new `emptyOnDelete` property
4. run `cdk deploy` again

Annoying, but it seems to get it done.